# Simple CSS Hover Problem?

Tags: css

I don't understand why my anchor hover isn't causing the div box below to turn yellow.   Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a {background-color:Blue; width:400px; height:200px;}
#hide { width:500px; height:500px;background-color:black; }
a:hover #hide {background-color:yellow; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a>hover</a>
<div id="hide">turn yellow</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm very tired right now, so I must be overlooking something simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the `<a>` before introducing `hide`, so the path

```
a:hover #hide
```

will never apply.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML should look like this for your CSS to work:

```
<a>hover
  <div id="hide">turn yellow</div>
</a>
```

But again I am afraid It isn't valid markup. To work around that, you could have wrapped that into another `div`:

```
<div>hover
  <div id="hide">turn yellow</div>
</div>
```

But yet if you did in CSS:

```
div:hover{.....}
```

That won't work in IE6 because IE6 supports `:hover` pseudo selector only for links.

So the simple solution if you want to use a link (your markup structure):

```
<a id="link">hover</a>
<div id="hide">turn yellow</div>
```

You need to use javascript like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('link');
var dv = document.getElementById('hide');

el.onmouseover = function(){      
  dv.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
};

el.onmouseout = function(){
  dv.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

a:hover #hide - means you need to apply the style to a child contained inside the anchor tag

In the HTML you show, the DIV #hide is not a child of the anchor tag

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this will work.
I think you will have to color it via javascript:

```
<a onmouseover="document.getElementById("hide").stylebackgroundcolor='yellow'">hover</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover #hide {background-color:yellow; }
```

This does not exist, you want this:

```
a:hover div#hide
```

AND you want to put your div inside your anchor if this is your desired outcome:

```
<a>hover
  <div id="hide">turn yellow</div>
</a>
```

Comment: `a:hover #hide` and `a:hover div#hide` is basically the same selector.

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, this should work too (the adjacent sibling selector '+'):

```
a:hover + #hide {background-color:yellow;}
```

But that would be rather odd. The solutions that mention putting the `div` inside the `a` is the common form of the html. To make it valid html, however, the `div` needs to change to a `span` and then if you need the block qualities of a `div` set it to `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the other posters, you could place the `#hide` div inside the link; however, if you really wanted the div outside the link, you could use:

```
a:hover + #hide { background-color:yellow; }
```

This should style the element with id `hide` that comes directly after the link being hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

`a:hover #hide` targets an element with ID "hide" inside any a-element, for example this:

```
<a href="...">
<span id="hide">...</span>
</a>
```

What you're really after in your case is `a:hover + #hide`, as this would mean "the element with id "hide" right after an anchor element which is being hovered".